# Ubuntu/Linux: how are startup parameters typically defined for startup scripts (sysvinit)?

Tags: linux, startup, init.d

I'm curious as to what's the standard method of telling a startup script to execute with certain parameters.

For instance with MySQL, there's my.cnf, and from what I can tell, the startup parameters are derived by configuration options specified in my.cnf (i.e. `--bind-address=127.0.0.1` corresponds to `bind-address` option in the my.cnf file and so on).

I always assumed that every daemon/service would have a configuration file in `/etc/<some_app>` and that these startup options are determined with it.  However, I've ran into several daemon/services that I can't find where/how it determines what parameters to startup with.  `/etc/init.d/<some_script>` usually has several conditionals and the usual defaults, but I'm not sure where these startup options are actually determined.  Couple of examples are `pure-ftpd` and `mediatomb`; can't tell from the init.d script how the parameters are defined: the former has a `conf/` sub-directory with files representing startup options (these seem to be a Debian/Ubuntu specific configuration method as the `apt` package installs the `pure-ftpd-wrapper` which references these conf files). With mediatomb, there's just a config.xml file.

I guess the question could be phrased as, "if you're looking to change startup options for a typical package-installed daemon/service application on a Debian-like system, where should you look?"

Answer (score 1):

For many services you would look in `/etc/default/{service}` a script fragment that allows you to insert/modify command line options for services that can't be configured by just modifying a configuration file.

This pattern is not followed by every service though.  Sometimes you have to edit the `/etc/init.d/{service}` file directly.

One quick thing is to do a `grep source` for the `/etc/init.d/{service}` you are curious about.  Most start scripts are using the dash or bash.  The start up scripts frequently load the configuration from `/etc/default/{service}` or elsewhere by having a command like `source /etc/default/{service}` towards the top of the startup script.

Answer (score 0):

Third link on a google search for pure-ftp:

http://www.ubuntu-howto.info/howto/how-to-install-and-configure-pure-ftpd

Mediatomb Documentation:

http://mediatomb.cc/pages/documentation#id2856319

You should also consult the respective man pages for each package.