# Linux: How to pass parameters to `service foo start` (at command line)?

Tags: redhat, service

I'd like to pass an argument to the service I am starting.
E.g. starting a server in a debug mode. Like,

```
service jboss-as start debug
```

Or such.
But `service` seems not to support that.

Is there some way?  (For RHEL 6 if that matters.)

Note: This is similar to [Ubuntu/Linux: how are startup parameters typically defined for startup scripts (sysvinit)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/279537/ubuntu-linux-how-are-startup-parameters-typically-defined-for-startup-scripts) but not the same.

Comment: Stop, ubuntu doesn't use sysv, it uses upstart.

Comment: Create another case in startup script. Example: `start-debug` and then you can run: `/etc/init.d/jboss-as start-debug`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In RHEL you have /etc/sysconfig folder. Here you define startup parameters.
And in your startup script you include something like:

```
if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/$prog ] ; then
    . /etc/sysconfig/$prog
fi
```

Check existing services for examples.

For development you can put your startup parameters in an exported variable (for example in .bashrc) which you can manually override any time you wish.

**EDIT**

If you really want to use `service` there are some other options.

Your script should support at least `start` and `stop`. But you can also implement a `debug` command. And start your program with:

```
service foo debug
```

Another way will be to check for the second argument in your script and you start your program with:

```
service foo start debug
```

Modify your init script to something like:

```
case "$1" in
  start)
        if [ "$2" = "debug" ]
        then
                start_debug
        else
                start
        fi
        ;;
```

Comment: As for the exported environment vars, that appears not to be the case - service's man page says that TERM and LANG are the only ones which are passed to the script. But of course, one can always bypass service by running /etc/init.d/MyNiftyService start whatever1 whatever2...

Comment: I will resort to Alien's bypass. Want to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu, startup parameters are typically found in:

```
/etc/default/<service_name>
```

Comment: Right but I don't want to change that every time I need a change... During development it's quite often. And I need RHEL 6. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure an `EnvironmentFile` in your service file:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/my-service
ExecStart=my-service.sh ${ARG1} ${ARG2}
```

and create the `/etc/sysconfig/my-service` with the vars:

```
ARG1=first
ARG2=second
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with sourcing additional parameters from a system specific file after checking for its existence, as suggested above.

I do not like adding any additional options to the service startup.